# golang test : use assert to compare addresses leads to runtime crash

Tags: go, testing, crash, assert

I'm trying to compare 2 addresses, I can write code like `p == q`, but inside ```assert, it leads to run time problem, as below:

```
import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestAddress(t *testing.T) {
    assert := assert. New(t)
    p := new(int)
    q := new(int)
    assert.NotEqual(p, q) // error

    var a struct{}
    var b struct{}
    assert. Equal(a, b)

    i1 := new([0]int)
    i2 := new([0]int)
    assert.NotEqual(i1, i2) // error
}
```

The error message is:

```
Error Trace:    d:\mycode\basic_test.go:11

            Error:          Should not be: (*int)(0xc0000178b8)

            Test:           TestAddress

Error Trace:    d:\mycode\basic_test.go:19

            Error:          Should not be: &[0]int{}

            Test:           TestAddress
```

What does this error message indicate? How to fix it?

Comment: You are using `NotEqual` to assert that the values to which `p` and `q` point are NOT equal, but they ARE equal, they are both `0`. Hence the `Should not be: ...` error. Same for the other assert.

Answer (score 0):

As per `assert.NotEqual` [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert#NotEqual)

> NotEqual asserts that the specified values are NOT equal.
>
> a.NotEqual(obj1, obj2)
>
> Pointer variable equality is determined based on the equality of the referenced values (as opposed to the memory addresses).

Given that `p` and `q` points to the same value, the assertion fails, resulting in those error messages.